# Angular request not getting sent

Tags: angular, httprequest

This was working earlier.. can't get my head around why the request is not getting sent.

The Angular app has an initializer function

```
export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
  return () => new Promise(resolve => {
    // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
    accountService.refreshToken()
      .subscribe()
      .add(resolve);
  });
}
```

accountService.refreshToken() is as below

```
  refreshToken() {
    console.log('checking refr tkn')
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.reqUrl}/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(map(account => {
        console.log('res for checking refr tkn');
        if(account){
          this.accountSubject.next(account);
          this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
          return account;
        }
      }));
  }
```

The console log shows 'checking refr tkn', but does not send request. Not sure why?

Comment: The error:
```Error in app comp onInit TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
    at HttpXhrBackend.handle (http.js:1568)  at ErrorInterceptor.intercept (error-interceptor.ts:20)   at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)    at JwtInterceptor.intercept (jwt.interceptor.ts:26)   at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)  at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1886)  at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)   at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1936)  at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1082)  at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:44)```

Comment: So the seconf log ('res for checking refr tkn') is not being printed?

Comment: @gerstams Yes. second console.log statement is not getting printed

Comment: problem found.. it was in jwt interceptor, where a new blank request was added to next() if user was not validated. Corrected it now.